# TypeScript React, unable to send props to component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have a simple button component, I am styling it with styled components, but I can not send a simple prop to the component as TypeScript complains with `No overload matches this call`

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';

import Button from '../form/button';

export const App = (): React.ReactElement => <Button secondary>Click me</Button>;
```

Button.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: ${({ secondary }) => (secondary ? 'white' : 'red')};
`;

interface Props {
  children: string;
  secondary?: any;
}

const Button: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, secondary }) => (
  <StyledButton secondary={secondary}>{children}</StyledButton>
);

export default Button;
```

This should work, what does TypeScript needs me to specify? The error is not very helpful

Comment: try <Button secondary={'true'}>Click me</Button>

Comment: @Sam, still says `No overload matches this call`

Comment: @Álvaro `children: React.ReactNode` and `secondary: boolean`

Comment: @RameshReddy, same `No overload matches this call`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-silence-uwv7z?file=/src/Button.tsx here is the working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you haven't passed the props to the styled component, so it does not know what `secondary` is.

You can pass your props like so (and I removed `children` since you don't need to specify this manually)

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

interface Props {
  secondary?: any;
}

const StyledButton = styled.button<Props>`
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: ${({ secondary }) => (secondary ? "white" : "red")};
`;


const Button: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, secondary }) => (
  <StyledButton secondary={secondary}>{children}</StyledButton>
);

export default Button;
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-worker-62xtm?file=/src/form/Button.tsx

Comment: Thanks, It turns out I still needed to change the type to boolean on secondary for it to work, but with that and your changes is good now

Comment: Yes, `boolean` is what you should be using. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify that the props passed and then destructured are from the interface `Props` and access the parameter `secondary`.

```
const StyledButton = styled.button`
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: ${({secondary}: Props) => (secondary ? 'white' : 'red')}
`;
```